# cake php pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I have a website running on cakephp. I want to implement pagination there.

I have a result set in an array. and I have included the paginator helper.

Can someone tell me how to apply pagination to my result.

Comment: There is some good documentation in the cookbook on this but I think Mauro's answer is what you need. This is a common question and I'm sure if you give us some code you might have an "ah-ha" moment.

Answer (score 3):

The CakePHP Cookbook has a very detailed section about pagination. Also covers how to write pagination for custom data. The Cookbook itself is highly recommended while developing in Cake.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/164/Pagination

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a result set in an array and you want to paginate, then you already made a find() call and you can’t paginate that (at least not using the cake’s paginator). You need to call the pagination method in replacement to the find.